# Delegation Among Container View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, delegation

I have a parent viewcontroller hosting 3 container viewcontrollers.

At certain points I need to pass data from one container viewcontroller to another container viewcontroller and thought I could accomplish this through the delegation pattern. However, I can't seem to figure out why the delegate is not triggered and the receiving container viewcontroller doesn't receive any data.

Can't seem to spot what's potentially wrong with the way I've set it up. If there's a recommended way to pass data between the containers, I'm all ears as well!

Below is a code summary on the setup:

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController { 

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let firstContainerVC = segue.destination as? FirstContainerVC {
            //....
        }

        if let secondContainerVC = segue.destination as? SecondContainerVC {
           //....
        }        
    }
        protocol Delegate {
           func passX(a: String?)
           func passY(b: String?)
        }
}    

class FirstContainerVC: UIViewController {

    var delegate: Delegate?

    if isTrue {
        delegate.passX(a: "TestOne")
    } else {
        delegate.passY(b: "TestTwo")
    }
}

class SecondContainerVC: UIViewController, Delegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let firstVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstContainer") as! FirstContainerVC
    firstVC.delegate = self
    }

    func passX(a: String?) {
        //if let a = a....
    }

    func passY(b: String?) {
        //if let b = b....
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the second container view controller instantiating the first container view controller if they're all contained in the same parent view controller?

Comment: @slickdaddy i thought i'd have to instantiate it to grab the delegate property, sorry im fairly new to this, do you mind elaborating on the suggested way?

Comment: Post your parent view controller and I'll explain.

Comment: @slickdaddy re-posted, not sure if it provides the detail as i embedded the VCs through storyboard, but seeing smartcats comment below, im thinking i need to reorganize my inherited delegate elsewhere...to the parent?

Comment: When you say the parent view controller contains the 3 other view controllers, do you mean that you've explicitly established a parent-child relationship between them? Or do you just mean that all 3 view controllers are navigated to from the parent view controller?

Comment: i would have to say the latter(?)...where i had dragged a container view into my parent view controller creating an embedded segue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't know how the dragging and dropping works in Xcode, I do everything in code. However, when your parent view controller instantiates another view controller, just set the parent as the container's delegate.

Create the protocol:

```
protocol SomeProtocol: AnyObject {
    func passX(a: String?)
    func passY(b: String?)
}
```

And the containers will have delegates of type that protocol:

```
class FirstContainerVC: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: SomeProtocol?
}

class SecondContainerVC: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: SomeProtocol?
}
```

The parent must conform to the protocol so that it can become the delegate. Then when you instantiate the containers (which you must only do once in this scenario), set `self` as their delegates:

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController, SomeProtocol {

    // make the containers instance properties so that you
    // can access them from the protocol methods
    weak var firstContainerVC = FirstContainerVC()
    weak var secondContainerVC = SecondContainerVC()

    // set the delegates at some point
    func setDelegates() {
        firstContainerVC?.delegate = self
        secondContainerVC?.delegate = self
    }

    func passX(a: String?) {
        guard let a = a else {
            return
        }
        secondContainerVC?.getFromFirst(a: a)
    }

    func passY(b: String?) {
        //
    }

}
```

Then when you want to go from first to second, go through the delegate from the first container to the parent, and from the parent to the second container.

```
class FirstContainerVC: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: SomeProtocol?

    func sendToSecond() {
        delegate?.passX(a: "slick")
    }

}

class SecondContainerVC: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: SomeProtocol?

    func getFromFirst(a: String) {
        print(a)
    }

}
```

This is a somewhat crude example. You should code your implementation how you feel most comfortable (i.e. gracefully unwrapping, how/where you instantiate, etc.). Also, if all of the view controllers are permanent view controllers (meaning that they are never deallocated), no need to make them `weak var`. However you do it, the concepts are all the same. The parent is the delegate for the containers, and the containers communicate with each other through the parent.

Some people may suggest using notification observers or singletons for the containers to communicate with each other, but I find that to be overkill when you have a parent right there.

Comment: appreciate the clear walkthrough, but having rearranged my code in the following way, im unfortunately still not seeing the protocol function triggered from the parent and subsequently to the receiving/ending container controller function..any other advice or maybe i can show?

Comment: If `FirstContainerVC` wants to send something to `SecondContainerVC`, the first container sends that thing to the parent using the delegate `delegate?.passX(a: "slick")`. That method is called in the parent. The parent then passes it to the second view controller with `secondContainerVC?.getFromFirst(a: a)`.

Comment: i found my issue...needed to assign the delegate of the firstContainerVC to the parent in the parent prepareForSegue method per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235071/using-delegate-between-sibling-view-controllers-in-containers appreciate getting me steered in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @slickdaddy that your second container view controller has no business instantiating your first container view controller.  I suspect you already had a first container VC and now you have 2.

To answer your question about the best way to pass the data, your container view controllers should know nothing about the parent view controller.  Through either delegation or a callback that the parent registers, the data should go to the parent and the parent should then route it down to the other interested contained view controllers.

Keep knowledge of your hierarchy flowing "downwards". In other words, contained or owned VCs should not know anything about their owners or parents. It'll help with reuse, organization, etc..

Also consider another approach:  passing the same model object into each contained view controller.

And finally, my preferred approach is letting each view controller (or actually its view model if doing MVVM) reach for a DependencyManager singleton where such model objects live.  If done right, unit tests can still have full control by injecting mock models into the DependencyManager.